# What could cause Retrofit to ignore method invocation?

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I have ran into a strange behavior. My app has a main activity which consists of navdrawer layout and the default list fragment. The list fragment uses Retrofit client to fetch contents. The detail view is shown when a list item is selected. On a small screen, the detail view is loaded through a separate activity. That activity also uses a Retrofit client to fetch detailed information. Then, there is one option that can be selected from navdrawer that spawns a new activity. That activity too uses Retrofit client to send out data.

The list and detail activities invoke Retrofit methods just fine. I can see the logs and things are working as expected. However, the third activity, which is opened through a navigation option, attempts to invoke Retrofit client methods that are ignored by Retrofit.

In all instances, the Retrofit client is instantiated in the same way:

```
protected ServerApi buildApi(String serverEndpoint) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .create();

    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLog(new AndroidLog("ServerApi"))
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(serverEndpoint)
            .setErrorHandler(new ApiErrorHandler())
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();

    return restAdapter.create(ServerApi.class);
}
```

In the list and detail activities, I can see verbose Retrofit log entries. However, when I make a call to the similarly constructed Retrofit client in the third activity, no logs go out, no error is thrown, logcat doesn't print anything. Its almost like the invocation is ignored.

I am sure that server end point is properly set and I also ensure that call is executed. At first, I thought that this may be due to creation of client happening in `onCreate` and executed on a separate thread. However, making a test invocation right after client creation doesn't produce any result.

Does anyone know what may cause such odd behavior just in one activity and not the rest?

**UPDATE 1**

Yes, I tried logging everywhere. My more desperate Retrofit client build looked like this:

```
protected class ApiErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Got API error " + cause);

        Response r = cause.getResponse();
        Throwable throwable = null;

        if (r == null) {
            return cause;
        }

        // Try to interpret the response
        String responseBody = new String(((TypedByteArray) r.getBody()).getBytes());
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        BaseResponse response = null;

        try {
            response = gson.fromJson(responseBody, BaseResponse.class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not parse the error response:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return new ServerApiException(response.getErrorMessage());
    }
}

protected class ApiRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Intercepted API request: " + request.toString());
    }
}

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setLog(new AndroidLog("ServerApi"))
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
    .setEndpoint(mServerUrl)
    .setErrorHandler(new ApiErrorHandler())
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .setRequestInterceptor(new ApiRequestInterceptor())
    .setProfiler(new Profiler() {
        @Override
        public Object beforeCall() {
            Log.d("RetrofitProfiler", "Before call to retrofit");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCall(Profiler.RequestInformation requestInfo, long elapsedTime, int statusCode, Object beforeCallData) {
            Log.d("RetrofitProfiler", String.format("HTTP %d %s %s (%dms)",
                    statusCode, requestInfo.getMethod(), requestInfo.getRelativePath(), elapsedTime));
        }
    })
    .build();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Ok, I was wrong but didn't know that Retrofit relied at least on one subscriber to be present. I guess it makes sense, now that I think about it... but its not fire-and-forget.

What I was doing wrong:

```
mClient = new ServerClient(mServerEndpoint, mAccountToken);
mUvClient.getFeed(mFeedId);
```

This is the part I didn't know. You need to subscribe to the observable in order for it to execute:

```
mClient = new ServerClient(mServerEndpoint, mAccountToken);
mUvClient.getFeed(mFeedId)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<FeedInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(FeedInfo feedInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG, "on Next");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "on completed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "on error");
        }
    });
```

This produces the expected Retrofit verbose logs and result. Anyway, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Do you log anything in your ErrorHandler?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I've updated the post with a build I used to try and log anything at all.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I resolved it... basically, I deconstructed my activity to bare minimum: onCreate with setContentView and client instantiation. That still produced no result. Then I thought "maybe I need to specify where the subscription happens". That also didn't work. Finally, I thought why not subscribe and see. That worked :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not subscribing to the Observable generated by the Retrofit API. I assumed that it would fire anyway but it didn't and needed a subscription. Hope this helps anyone else who may come across this issue.